# in custom Command/function checking if current buffer has sometext "selected" (v/V/C-v)

Tags: vim

I am having a custom command, in the command a function would be called.

I want to make sure that, the command is executed only if current buffer is in VISUAL mode (`v, V or C-V`). or, say, the function is executed only if some text in current buffer is currently selected.

- `visualmode()` I cannot use, because it gives the **last** visual mode type.
- I tried putting `echo mode()` in the function, it gives always `n`.
- and I am not sure, if I selected something, and press `:` it has already entered `command` mode, how can I check if the buffer has something in selection **right now**?

The solution could be easy, but I am stuck here.... can someone shed me some light? thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want that kind of functionality, you have to use a mapping (or two different mappings for normal and visual mode).

As you said, as soon as you press `:`, visual mode is left for command-line mode. However, as the `:'<,'>` range is automatically inserted, you can pass that range to your function and operate on that. That would allow use from normal mode via an explicit range, too, but this is just sensible and consistent with the built-in commands.

Comment: thank you Ingo for the answer. I know mapping can do something like that (e.g. vnoremap)..The `'<,'>` is not safe for me, because the range can be added by user manually. I want to have this logic in my function: If buffer has something selected right now, do sth. otherwise, print error msg.   can it somehow be checked in a function? (I want to just do something on the **current** selection, not previous)

Comment: Well, if the range is explicitly added by the user, isn't it reasonable that he wants the command to work on it? To avoid the XY problem, I would need to know what the command actually does.

Comment: The only hack I can think of is mapping `:` in both visual and normal modes, and setting a `g:came_from_visual_mode` flag. Then you would know for sure. But it's ugly.

Comment: ok, for example, I want to append a text: `"Hello"` at the end of each line in user's current selection, no matter `v V or <c-v>`, but not the last `gv`

Comment: thank you. I think I better do some refactory and use some plugable mapping. But that hack is clever, I must say.  +1

Comment: The last `gv` has nothing to do with it. From normal mode, without an explicit range, it would default to the current line. Trick: If you use `:command -range=-1` and then check for `<count> == -1`, you can detect normal mode invocation without a given range and print an error message. Isn't that close enough?!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39356/discussion-between-kent-and-ingo-karkat)

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to figure out the same problem myself, and I came up with this.

With this autocmd:

```
autocmd CursorMoved * let s:Mode = mode()
```

A command like the following that also uses range option `-range=0` that alters the `<count>` argument (0 when no range is passed, other wise the same number as the line the command is called on):

```
command! -range=0 CmdName call FuncName(<count>, <line1>, <line2>)
```

Then with logic like this you can check for either a visual selection, a normal range being passed, and no range passed at all:

```
function! FuncName(count, firstLine, lastLine)
    if a:count == 0 "no range given 
            "do stuff for no given range
    else
        if s:Mode  =~ '\vV|v|'  "range was given
            "do stuff for visual selection
        else 
            "do stuff for normal range
            " w/ a:firstLine & a:lastLine 
        endif
    endif
endfunction
```

**NOTES:**

- **Known Problem -** The only case I have found this doesn't work is when a visual selection is only one character ( the cursor wasn't moved), but for most cases this shouldn't be an issue.
- **Command Note -** You have to pass  and  as arguments rather than using the before call, so a invalid range isn't passed.

Comment: nice to see you here Ryan. thanks for the solution. I thought of this when I wanted to do that with command. but this way is not reliable. except for the situation you mentioned, you could try in a buffer, `v` select some text, now the var should be `v`, fine. now, press `ESC`, and then `: somecommand`. If you check the variable, it would be still `v`. which is not correct.

Comment: Your right, but there is a way around this by using the `-range=0` or `-range=-1` like @Ingo suggested in one of his comments. Then you can determine if a range has been given. So when you press `v` select some text `ESC` then `: somecommand` no range is passed (no '<'>) and you can test for it.  I'll update the answer how I handle it.

Comment: The thing is, I don't want to check `'< '>` at all. no matter they were there or not. because they could be manually added or removed. I cannot know if the moment user pressed `:cmd` the user was in `v/V`. I clarified it with Igno in chat. :) so the information was not shown here. If you can click the link, you will see the conversation.

Comment: Yeah this way doesn't ignore `<'` and `'>` but if the user does add them in when a visual selection isn't used it treats them differently than a if the user selects text then calls a command.

Comment: I don't care whether the range was manually added or not, I'm just trying to know whether to include a "visual selection" `\%V` anchor in a regex I build in my command. For my purposes, if a range was given at all, it's enough to check that the visual range is equal to the passed-in range. Nice workaround with the `-range=0` to determine whether a range was passed at all!